# How do Chrono Trigger's SNES and DS versions differ?

Tags: nintendo-ds, snes, chrono-trigger

What are the main differences between the SNES and DS versions of *Chrono Trigger*?

Comment: OMG, I LOVED CHRONO TRIGGER!

Comment: Good question ... I always wanted to know ...

Comment: @Jarrod "loved"? past tense? what made you stop?

Comment: @Kip my SNES died about 14 years ago and I sold all my games :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a [post on Gamespot](http://www.gamespot.com/users/LarkAnderson/show_blog_entry.php?topic_id=m-100-25579069) listing some differences. Some examples:

- "The addition of a DS style combat system, which simply moves the commands from the top screen into the bottom screen, clearing up the screen a bit"
- "New items. If you thought Rainbow was ridiculous there's a new sword for Crono that's more powerful and has a 90% critical hit rate."

Comment: Can you please put the entire list in your answer, including the spoiler changelist with sufficient warning that it features spoilers?

Comment: The link to Gamespot is now dead (there is some other unrelated content there). Can someone else provide a definitive list?

Answer (score 10):

The main differences are:

- All the PS1 version movies are included
- New control scheme for DS
- Minimap added
- Encyclopedia added:

  - Items
  - Monsters
  - Art
  - Maps
  - Endings
- New content:

  - Several new dungeons and sidequests
  - Monster battle arena
  - 1 new ending
  - Items
  - Monsters & Bosses
- New translation